# EF Core can't include children in parent

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm quite new to EF Core.

In my DB Context:

```
// STEP
modelBuilder.Entity<CorsoStepS>().HasKey(x => new { x.codCorso, x.codStep });
modelBuilder.Entity<CorsoStepS>()
    .HasMany(step => step.CorsoStepLezioni)
    .WithOne(lez => lez.CorsoStep)
    .HasForeignKey(lez => new { lez.codCorso, lez.codStep });
modelBuilder.Entity<CorsoStepS>().Ignore(step => step.CorsoStepLezioni);
////

// LEZIONI
modelBuilder.Entity<CorsoStepLezione>().HasKey(x => new { x.codCorso, x.codStep, x.codLezione });
modelBuilder.Entity<CorsoStepLezione>()
    .HasMany(lez => lez.Sessioni)
    .WithOne(sess => sess.Lezione)
    .HasForeignKey(sess => new { sess.codCorso, sess.codStep, sess.codLezione });
modelBuilder.Entity<CorsoStepLezione>().Ignore(lez => lez.Sessioni);
////

// SESSIONI
modelBuilder.Entity<CorsoStepLezioneSessione>().HasKey(x => new { x.codCorso, x.codStep, x.codLezione, x.codSessione });
modelBuilder.Entity<CorsoStepLezioneSessione>()
    .HasMany(sess => sess.Iscrizioni)
    .WithOne(iscr => iscr.Sessione)
    .HasForeignKey(iscr => new { iscr.CodCorso, iscr.CodStep, iscr.CodLezione, iscr.CodSessione });
modelBuilder.Entity<CorsoStepLezioneSessione>().Ignore(sess => sess.Iscrizioni);
////
```

My entities:

```
public class CorsoStepS
    {
        public int codCorso { get; set; }
        public int codStep { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
        public int maxPartecipanti { get; set; }
        public int order { get; set; }

        public virtual Corso Corso { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CorsoStepLezione> CorsoStepLezioni { get; set; }
    }

public class CorsoStepLezione
    {
        public int codCorso { get; set; }
        public int codStep { get; set; }
        public int codLezione { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }


        public CorsoStepS CorsoStep { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CorsoStepLezioneSessione> Sessioni { get; set; }
    }

public class CorsoStepLezioneSessione
    {
        public int codCorso { get; set; }
        public int codStep { get; set; }
        public int codLezione { get; set; }
        public int codSessione { get; set; }
        public DateTime? data { get; set; }
        public string ora { get; set; }
        public int maxPartecipanti { get; set; }

        public virtual CorsoStepLezione Lezione { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CorsoStepLezioniSessioniIscrizione> Iscrizioni { get; set; }
    }
```

When I call:

```
var lezioniCorso = _clienteContext.CorsoStepLezioni
                .Include(lezione => lezione.Sessioni);
```

it gives me:
The expression 'lezione.Sessioni' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.

But if I call:

```
var lezioniCorso = _clienteContext.CorsoStepLezioni
                .Include(lezione => lezione.CorsoStep);
```

it's ok.

what am I doing wrong? I'm going stupid

Comment: Why do you have these `Ignore` statements? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of this line

`modelBuilder.Entity<CorsoStepLezione>().Ignore(lez => lez.Sessioni);`

First you are telling EF to build up the relationship and then immediately ignore it again so EF acts as if this property does not exist.